# Could not find file when I tried to read upload Excel CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, csv, model-view-controller

I am trying to read specific column in my excel CSV file. Because the file is uploaded I don't want to hard code the filepath to a specific location. When I run the code I have the error 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\North_HCA_Texts3.csv'.
 The file exist because I selected it from my desktop

HTML

```
   <div class="col-md-10">
       <input type="file" name="attachmentcsv" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" class="form-control" id="attachmentcsv" />

                </div>
```

C#

```
 struct LineInMyCsvFile
    {
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string EMPLOYEENUMBER { get; set; }
        public string JOBTITLEROLE { get; set; }
        public string BAND { get; set; }
    }

     string filePath = string.Empty;
     string path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Uploads/");                  
     filePath = Path.GetFileName(attachmentcsv.FileName);

   IEnumerable<LineInMyCsvFile> allRecords = null;

  using (var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath)) // error here
  {
     var csvParser = new CsvParser(reader);
      CsvReader r = new CsvReader(csvParser);
      allRecords = r.GetRecords<LineInMyCsvFile>().ToArray();
   }
   foreach (var record in allRecords)
   {
     // Imagine you only care about the value in MobileNumber:
      listmobilenumber.Add(record.MobileNumber);
   }
```

Comment: If you have selected it from your 'desktop' then why would you expect it to be under 'Program Files'? Second, you have Server.MapPath() there, is this a web application? If so does the web user have access to the location?

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes this is a web application. I am still running it using localhost. I selected the file form my desktop I am a bit confuse to why the location is program files

Comment: Provide whatever the correct path is.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the exception is that you are not using `path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Uploads/");` in your code.

Comment: Please any idea how to use path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Uploads/"); in my code I am new to CSV Upload

Comment: you can use something like filePath = Path.Combine(path, attachmentcsv.FileName);